# Autodiscover in new Outlook 2016 setup not working

Tags: outlook, outlook-2016, autodiscover

I am setting up a new emailserver, and I want to use autodiscover on it to let Outlook autoconfigure itself. In my current situation I have multiple virtual domains and only one certificate, so I use `mail.example.com` as STMP, POP and IMAP server.

This is my `autodiscover.xml`:

```
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
  <Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a">
    <User>
      <DisplayName>email@example.com</DisplayName>
    </User>
    <Account>
      <AccountType>email</AccountType>
      <Action>settings</Action>
      <Protocol>
        <Type>IMAP</Type>
        <Server>mail.example.com</Server>
        <Port>993</Port>
        <DomainRequired>off</DomainRequired>
         <LoginName>email@example.com</LoginName>
        <SPA>off</SPA>
        <SSL>on</SSL>
        <AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
      </Protocol>
      <Protocol>
        <Type>POP3</Type>
        <Server>mail.example.com</Server>
        <Port>995</Port>
        <DomainRequired>off</DomainRequired>
        <LoginName>email@example.com</LoginName>
        <SPA>off</SPA>
        <SSL>on</SSL>
        <AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
      </Protocol>
      <Protocol>
        <Type>SMTP</Type>
        <Server>mail.example.com</Server>
        <Port>587</Port>
        <DomainRequired>off</DomainRequired>
          <LoginName>email@example.com</LoginName>
        <SPA>off</SPA>
        <SSL>on</SSL>
        <AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
      </Protocol>
    </Account>
  </Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

My email address passes the AutoDiscovery test at  `https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com`
[image: Connection Test Pass]

I can see Outlook requesting the file in the NGINX log:

```
[28/Feb/2018:22:04:31 +0100] "POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 1658 "-" "Microsoft Office/16.0 (Windows NT 10.0; MAPI 16.0.8431; Pro)"
```

The configuration works with the old autoconfiguration dialog:
[image: Old Autoconfiguration Dialog]
[image: Configured account in old autoconfig dialog]

The configuration doesn't work with the new "Welcome to Outlook" dialog (ZeroConfig I believe it's called) 
[image: New ZeroConfig Welcome to Outlook dialog]
[image: Config failure]

When I click "Change account type" and then "IMAP", it has the correct settings listed. But when I check my `mail.log`, I see Outlook hasn't tried any of those settings while auto-configuring.

I have the problem on both my desktop and laptop, both running Office build 1708.

[image: Version dialog]

Has anybody got the same problems or can anybody help me in the right direction? I've wasted way too much time on this problem now.

**EDIT**:

To clarify, I'm not running an Exchange server. I only want to let Outlook know the correct IMAP and POP. 
I've tested the autodiscover with the tool in the contextmenu, and it lists the correct settings, but the "Simpified Account Creation" dialog still fails and doesn't connect to IMAP, POP, or SMTP. It does however connect to https://mail.example.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml.

Comment: So, you’re running an exchange server, why are you using Nginx and a static autodiscover file for your clients? Exchange hosts the autodiscover webpage and clients should be pointed there through one of several methods. This process is well documented. If you want to test autodiscover then open Outlook and right-click the tray icon while holding CTRL and you will get an option to test autodiscover and get more details about exactly what Outlook is trying to do and failing on. It tries 4 or 5 different methods before giving up.

Comment: To clarify; the server is NOT an exchange server. I've manually made an autodiscover.xml to let Outlook know the settings it has to connect to.

Comment: I've tested the autodiscover with the tool in the contextmenu, it lists the correct settings, but the "Simpified Account Creation" dialog still fails and doesn't connect to IMAP, POP, or SMTP. It does however connect to https://mail.example.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

Answer (score -1):

Is this "emailserver" an Exchange server?

As far as I know, the **Simplified Account Creation** feature will help end user to setup Outlook profile with some **well-known** account, for example: Office 365, Gmail, Outlook.com. However, it not works for particular account.

I suppose that your email domain is a new created domain in Internet, thus we need to manually configure your account by selecting IMAP account type.

Comment: To clarify; the server is NOT an exchange server. I've manually made an autodiscover.xml to let Outlook know the settings it has to connect to.

Comment: The weird thing is, if it only sets up well-known user accounts, why does it request the autodiscover.xml from my webserver?

Comment: yep same problem been using autodiscover.xml for almost 20 years until now. using standalone http server.  works with outlook 2012 not 2016.